# is this leftshift or something diferent?

Tags: bit-manipulation

I am searching left shift operation like this:

```
101110111 <<< 3
101110111
110111101
```

but instead of that I found left shift operation like below in every online calculator

```
101110111 << 3 = 101110111000
```

My question is, are they different left shift types and is there any online bitwise calculator out there that calculates as shown above.

Comment: It's a left-rotate. Of 9 bits, oddly, but you can do that. Hopefully it's not a weird "variable-width" rotate, which is really hard to implement and as far as I know not even useful.

Answer (score 0):

The operation you are after is a bitwise left-rotate. For example the windows calculator supports it in "Programmer Mode", where it is called "RoL" for rotate left. Left shift ("Lsh") is also supported, for which zeros are inserted as you correctly observed.